# Combine two rows based on common ID

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2012, sql-merge

I have a query that returns two lines per `ID`. I would like to be able to merge these into one single row, based on the `ID`.

There will only ever be two rows per `ID`. As in the example below, one row will only ever contain `ColumnA` and the other row will contain `ColumnB`.

So this is a simplified version of how the data looks at the moment:

[image]

And this is how I would like it to be, although I'm not entirely sure how to go about it:

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do this by aggregation:

```
select ID, max(ColumnA) ColumnA, max(ColumnB) ColumnB 
from TableName
group by ID
```